# adding margin-left creates horizontal scroll bar to white space

Tags: html, css

I'm writing the CSS for my site. I have text that I am putting on top of my background image. My HTML and CSS is below:

HTML

```
<header class="site-header">


        <div class="site-header__menu-icon">
            <div class="site-header__menu-icon__middle"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="site-header__menu-content">
            <div class="site-header__btn-container">
                <a href="#" class="btn open-modal">Request A Demo</a>
            </div>
            <nav class="primary-nav primary-nav--pull-right">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#our-beginning" id="our-beginning-link">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#testimonials" id="testimonials-link">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#testimonials" id="testimonials-link">Why Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


    <div class="section">
        <picture>
            <img src="assets\images\pepper.jpg">
        </picture>
        <div>
            <div class="section__text-content">
                <h1 class="section__title">Company</h1>
                <h3 class="section__sub-title">Company Slogan</h3>
                <div class="btn-container">
                    <a class="btn" href="#">Talk To A Specialist</a>
                    <a class ="btn btn__white btn__pepper-white" href="#">Get A Quote</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.section {
    position: relative; 
    max-width: 100%;

    &__text-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left:
    }

    &__title {
        font-size: 7rem;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #ffffff;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    &__sub-title {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-top: 3%;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I try to add a margin-left to the `.section` class in my CSS, because then a blank which space to the right of my screen appears with a horizontal scroll bar in direct proportion to the amount of margin I specified to move to the left.

I know that I could use a simple "background-image" for my css, but I'd prefer to do it this way for responsive imaging (it's how I learned to do it and I'm on a bit of a time crunch).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please share the image (pepper.jpg) ?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED

My problem was I was writing my margin in relative terms by doing:

```
.section__text-content {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 10%
}
```

Which is wrong, because the `&__text-content` is set to `position: absolute`

Percentage is relative position, with an absolutely positioned image you need absolute margins (i.e. pixels)